# Recommended database to use for matching type queries

Tags: database-design

We have 2 sets of objects that need to be matched based on a set of question responses/attributes in terms of a percentage (similar to dating based algorithms) and to then be able to provide a list of best possible matches for a given person. The data set can grow quite large possibly into the millions so there is an elimination type matching based on geolocation, gender, etc and then the matching algorithm finds the best possible match in what is remaining.

I would like to know

1. What would be the recommended database to store this kind of data?
2. Is the matching calculation done real time or do we do it and store it in the data structure (the set of attributes/questions can grow over time... a person can answer additional questions)?
   in order to be able to do the matching algorithm calculations

Comment: "*What would be the recommended database to store this kind of data?*" - You haven't provided the structure of the data itself, which is necessary for answering this. Does the shape of the structure remain fairly constant? Please provide some example queries (even if in pseudocode) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: simple columns

- Column "hair", value "blonde"
- Column "eyes", value "blue"

This requires a database that can use several indices in a query, for example postgres' bitmap index scans. However, one column per attribute is very cumbersome if the number of attributes is not fixed or some questions can be multiple-choice. So I'm mentioning this method as an example of what not to do. In addition using one index per column introduces performance problems for low cardinality values, for example "gender".

Option 2: attributes

Let's consider one "attribute" to be a (question_id,answer_id) pair, and want to search on objects having the highest number of attributes in common. One answer would be to create a (question_id,answer_id) table, index both columns, and do something like a star join on it. This is usually very slow because the database will have to read then filter out lots of rows.

**Suggestion #1: use a fulltext search engine.**

Instead of viewing (question_id,answer_id) as a pair of numbers, let's view it as a "word" like "q12a5" for question_id=12 and answer_id=5. So each object would have a short text column containing one "word" for each of its attributes.

Then index this with a fast fulltext search engine (Xapian, Lucene, or whatever is integrated in your favorite database). These usually offer the feature you want, which is to order the results by the number of "words" in common between the query and the searched data. You will probably need to configure it to disable lexemization and other features meant to process natural language. The nice thing is a fulltext search engine is likely to be optimized for exactly what you want, and also competent at not getting bogged down by "very common words" which in your case are questions with few answers, producing low cardinality
for this particular attribute.

If some attributes overlap, for example

**Suggestion #2: postgres gist attribute search**

Postgresql has an [integer array type](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/14/intarray), which can be indexed with the gist index type. This allows mapping each (question_id,answer_id) to an int, and stuffing them into an array. Then, it is possible to make fast indexed searches on criteria like "array contains other array" or "array overlaps with other array". However this is less optimal for your use case because it does not natively support sorting by the number of common attributes.

However, if you add geolocation into the mix, it does changes things. Postgresql has an excellent indexing method for geolocation, allowing to quickly search records whose coordinates fit into a bounding box. A fulltext search engine is unlikely to offer this feature. So you could combine that with integer attributes.

**Option #3: NoSQL**

I'm not the one to ask about that, but I heard that some NoSQL databases offer the feature you want.

**Option #3: Clickhouse**

Perhaps you can combine its H3 geographic indexing and [fulltext](https://www.tinybird.co/blog-posts/text-search-at-scale-with-clickhouse), but it looks a bit complicated. You could also model your attributes as bit field and use bitHammingDistance.

Further reading:

You could look up information about how some dating sites are architected, notably PlentyOfFish.